# A list of all available Material-UI shorthand properties for styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, properties, styling

I am looking for a simple list of all available shorthand styling propertied available in MUI. I have once, a while ago, found it skimming through their documentation, and now I cannot find it anywhere. I am using [MUI v5](https://mui.com/).

For example: margin-top" would be "mt" and "margin-bottom" would be "mb".

```
<Stack mt={10} mb={10}>
  {props.children}
</Stack>
```

I hope there is someone out there that has an idea of what I am talking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found it! I do not know why it took me so long to find it. Here it is in case anyone is looking for it.

https://mui.com/system/properties/

Comment: I often go back and forth between if it's a good idea to use shorthand or not given new devs maybe not know what "p" means, but they often know what "padding" means.